# Debug a Windows Service with WCF library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, service

For some reason I'm unable to attach the Visual Studio 2010 debugger to my service which uses a WCF Service Library, I followed the MSDN tutorial from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#_Additional_Resources). When I install and run the service it works just fine, and I'm able to access everything from a Client GUI, but when I try to attach the debugger to the service I get the following WCF Service Host window that pops up with an error:

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:8000.  Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionAcceptor.StartAccepting()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
```

The issue is happening on myServiceHost.open() in the `OnStart()` function in the service as seen below:

```
public partial class ORAS : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        OWcfServiceLibrary.OService ORAS = new OService();
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 
        public ORAS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);//every minute
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Has_Alarm);
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(OrionService));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }
```

Comment: How exactly are you "unable to attach"?  Errors? Messages?  What I like to do with services is have them auto-detect when they're running in interactive mode (e.g. manually from the command-line) so that they can be debugged easier.  For more details http://bit.ly/LFEk6d

Comment: I can attach to the service executable, but then the above message pops up

Comment: here is the solution for your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283145/how-to-prevent-visual-studio-launch-wcfsvchost-exe-in-debuggin

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you have two attempts at something like `serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint()`, where the 1st was the service itself, and then again when you started debug.

You can step into service code if you:

1. Run Visual Studio "as Administrator".
2. Have the service running and ready.
3. Start your client code in debug and put a breakpoint on the line that calls into the service.

When your client code hits the breakpoint, use `Step Into (F11)` to move into service code.  If you're setup correctly, it'll seamlessly translate into service code where you can continue stepping.

An alternative:

1. Stop your service.
2. In your service's `OnStart()` method, place this line first:  `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`
3. Rebuild and then start the service
4. When that new code line is hit, you will get prompted for choosing a debugger...choose the already open project

That should drop you on the new `launch()` line.

Comment: This seems like a solution, but my Service is not being called by a client, rather it is doing some timer based tasks in the service its self that I'd like to debug. So the client isn't ever running just the service.exe

Comment: Updated answer with another option

Comment: BUUUUUT, on the start of my serviceHost the issue ooccures again. Question updated to include this