# Prevent auto-launching of WCF Service Host in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

Currently, I’m working on a solution with several WCF projects. **Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution** is disabled. All worked fine in Visual Studio 2015 and lower – no auto-launching of WCF Service Host.

Since the change to **Visual Studio 2017** the WCF projects are launched anyway. Not every time but occasionally. That consumes a lot of time and performance – sometimes several minutes. I’ve checked the WCF Options – checkbox for auto-launching of WCF Service Host is still unselected.

How can I disable these occasionally auto-launching of WCF Service Host in **Visual Studio 2017**?

---

**EDIT**

It was a bug and is now fixed in an upcoming release. See state of bug [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/36071/annoying-auto-launch-of-wcf-service-hosts-everytim.html) (Fixed - Pending Release).

Comment: The issue is still not fixed in 15.3.

Answer (score -1):

We have had the exact same issue once we upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017 -- WcfSvcHost would launch despite telling Visual Studio not to do that.  We found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435062/5600709:  we had to unload each WCF service project and edit each project manually by removing the GUID `{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}` from the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` node.  Once we did this, we no longer get the annoying WcfSvcHost launch.  A consequence of this change is that the "WCF Options" settings menu no longer appears in the project properties, but that doesn't matter for us.

Comment: Need to update the service references from time to time. By changing the GUID Visual Studio isn't able to launch the WCF service – so updating references within VS won’t be possible.